# What should we notice when one program contains both socket server and client?

Tags: c, sockets, server, winsockets

I'm using C on Linux.

I write a socket server program which is used to process a client's HTTP requests. When the program receives a specific request, it will connect to another HTTP server, send an HTTP request, receive the response, and then send a response to the client.

The code is like this:

```c
......
int server=socket(...);
......(socket initialization code)
......
listen(server,1);
char buff[1024]
while(1){
    int client=accept(server,...);
    recv(client,buff,1027,0);
    if(strcmp(buff,"specific request")==0){
        int sock=socket(...);
        ......(client socket initialization code)
        connnect(sock,......);
        send(sock,......);
        recv(sock,......);
        close(sock);
    }
    send(client,......);
    close(client);
}
```

But it contains many problems. For example, it should run `send(sock,......)` three times so that `recv(sock,......)` would not block permanently and receive correct data.

When I separate the code like this:

```c
......
int server=socket(...);
......(socket initialization code)
......
listen(server,1);
char buff[1024]
while(1){
    int client=accept(server,...);
    recv(client,buff,1027,0);
    send(client,......);
    close(client);
}
```

and

```c
int sock=socket(...);
......(client socket initialization code)
connnect(sock,......);
send(sock,......);
recv(sock,......);
close(sock);
```

They can both run correctly.

I wonder how to write the expected program which has both socket server and client.

Comment: You can use multiple threads.

Comment: I have tried multiple threads but it makes no effect.

Comment: @Pudron then you are not using the threads correctly, but we can't see what you actually tried, so please [edit] your question with new details.  If you don't want to use threads, then put the sockets into non-blocking mode and multiplex their I/Os in a single thread by using `select()` or `(e)poll()` in a loop to know when to read from or write to each socket.

Comment: Server thread -> producer-consumer queue ->  client thread.  Yes, it will work.